# Trouble implementing specifically just-the-docs theme using jekyll

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I have been able to install most other jekyll themes but this theme in particular I can not get to render. It always shows up just as markdown and never renders the theme. I've had this problem with other themes, usually it involved fixing the url and baseurl in config or some other theme setting.

Theme in question:
https://pmarsceill.github.io/just-the-docs/

I have tried implementing the theme in my own fresh jekyll build.

I have tried cloning the github repository at:
https://github.com/pmarsceill/just-the-docs

I have tried cloning the REALLY basic version using a remote theme:
https://github.com/pmarsceill/jtd-remote

The main thing I want right now is to clone the just-the-docs repository and create a fork that I can just edit, but I can't even get their working repo to work for me. I tried changing the url and baseurl and looked around the files for other things that might make it different for me vs them. Is there anything else I would have to chance?

I expect a rendered theme, I get a white background page with a bunch of text. I have tried copying their exact repo with no sucecess locally with jekyll serve or on github pages on my own repo.

Why is this theme not working when others are?

Answer (score 11):

I was having a similar problem and there has been an issue raised in the repo that seems like what you are describing: https://github.com/pmarsceill/just-the-docs/issues/148

This solved it for me - from a comment there:

I got the same error few days ago, my solution is separate config files for github and local machine. You can view my setup on https://github.com/taruma/hidrokit-nb/tree/master/docs.

For local (_config_local.yml):

```
# Local Setting
baseurl: ""
url: ""

# Theme
theme: "just-the-docs"
# remote_theme: pmarsceill/just-the-docs
```

For github (_config.yml):

```
# Remote Setting
baseurl: "/guidelines"
# url: ""

# Theme
# theme: "just-the-docs"
remote_theme: pmarsceill/just-the-docs
```

For live server on local machine, I run bundle exec jekyll serve --config _config_local.yml.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when testing just-the-docs locally and found that I would have to pass the absolute path to the "_site" directory using the `--baseurl` parameter:

```
bundle exec jekyll build --baseurl "C:/path/to/my/_site"
```

This causes the path to the "assets" folder (which, for example, includes the stylesheet) to be rendered correctly.